# C# .Net Core Firebase FirestoreDb Mocking with Moq

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, asp.net-core, google-cloud-firestore, moq

I am trying to mock the FirestoreDb (Google.Cloud.Firestore) for my unit tests.

But the class signature is:

```
public sealed class FirestoreDb {...}
```

So I get this error when I try to mock:

```
_firestoreDb = new Mock<FirestoreDb>();
```

System.NotSupportedException : Type to mock must be an interface, a delegate, or a non-sealed, non-static class.

Is there any way that I cam mock that DB so that I can write unit tests for all my handlers saving to Firestore Db?

Thanks!

Comment: Tightly coupling to 3rd part dependencies that you have no control over will result in the issue you are currently experiencing. Consider wrapping such dependencies behind abstractions that you control and can manipulate as needed for your isolated unit tests.

Comment: Show an example of how you are currently using `FirestoreDb`

Comment: await _firestoreDb.Document($"applications/{applicationDocument.id}").SetAsync(applicationDocument, SetOptions.MergeAll);

Comment: @Nkosi While I normally agree that the coupling is not ideal, we also cannot always afford to write a wrapper over every library we use.